# C# List elements lifetime Unity3d

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I just used List of string to store words from json file. I parsed the json and stored the values in the List. My script looks like this.

```
    public List <string> a = new List<string>();

void Start()
{
     //JSON Parsing
     var jd = JSONNode.Parse(jsonString);
     print (jd.Count);
     for(int no=0; no<jd["A"].Count;no++)
     {
        a.Add(jd["A"][no].Value);
     }
     print ("A => "+a.Count);
}
```

If I have 10 values from json, it is added to the List a. I get the print "A => 10". When I stop and run my project again my start method again does parsing and adds value to List a. But my List count is now 20. And if I run again, it will be 30 and so on. I tried it on device also. On device after uninstalling and again installing, I get it added to it and still get the count as 20. Is it always necessary to clear() the List in the Start() to make the count 0? If I am not doing Clear() before adding strings to List, it always keeps previous values even after stopping the app on editor and on device also.

Comment: it sounds weird. lifetime of the list should be handled by the mono runtime. if you stop playing the game and then restart it sound quite impossible that the list elements are still there.

Comment: Is this during you having a debugger attached to your Unity3D session?

Comment: If `jsonString` is not modified, it sounds like Start is called more than once maybe manually or via SendMessage. Do you see only one log output containing 20, 30... as count or more?

Comment: I forgot to mension about [ExecuteInEditMode]. I am using this in my class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the List private or use the "NonSerialized" attribute on the List variable if you are running your project in "ExecuteInEditMode".

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment about [ExecuteInEditMode](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html):

- that will cause the list to be persisted

  - you might want that when, for example, you are live editing a level or environment
    and you would want the final values/settings to persist across runs and builds.

Public fields would get serialized for persistence. [NonSerialized](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/NonSerialized.html) attribute might
be useful to prevent that field from being persisted.

An alternate way would be to identify what values/state etc you want to persist and which
ones you want reset when actually playing and then do that accordingly.